# jQuery selector of the element inside the next sibling

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can anyone tell me how to select the 'a' within the 'li' from the class 'active_page'?
I tried the following but it does not work:

```
if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
    go_to_page(new_page);
}


<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="previous_link" href="javascript:go_to_previous();">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page_link active_page" href="javascript:go_to_page(0)" longdesc="0">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(1)" longdesc="1">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(2)" longdesc="2">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="next_link" href="javascript:go_to_next();">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: _Can anyone tell me how to select the 'a' within the 'li' from the class 'active_page'?_ But the link has the class, so you'd just use the selector `$("a.active_page")`

Answer (score 4):

You have to go up one level since it's the `<li>` that are siblings:

```
if ($(".active_page").parent().next().children('.page_link').length) {

}
```

If that's a little verbose for you, you can use indices:

```
if ($(".page_link").eq($(".active_page").index("li .page_link") + 1)).length) {

}
```

Just to prove that these both work: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/t5NDX/

Comment: "*If that's a little verbose for you*...then here use this longer, less readable one"? Lol. +1 all the same

Comment: @nbrooks true, but there is one less method call

Comment: Yeah, but `parent` and `next` are simple O(1) operations. `children` also just accesses a property of the current DOM element. But using both `eq` and `index` require full DOM traversals and building up full collections of elements that you aren't going to end up using, since you only need 1.

Comment: I think I did not understand the OP question. Why isn't the answer simply **$("a.active_page")** as Archer suggested in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

`next` looks for a sibling, but the `a` element has no siblings. Its parent `li` does:

```
if($('.active_page').parent().next().find('.page_link').length){
    go_to_page(new_page);
}
```

Also, `length` is a number, don't compare it to `true`. If you want to know if `length` is not `0`, the above works.

Comment: wouldn't it have to be `.next().children('.page_link')` or `.next().find('.page_link')`?  The `<li>` itself is selected from `.next()` so the class filter will fail .. right?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Thanks, I somehow managed to miss that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are tryin to do but

```
$('.active_page');
```

itself should give you the `<a>` element